# Route to ParentComponent communication, best practise for login-status

Tags: angular

Are there such things as global variables in Angular 2 that can be changed from all components? All I can find right now are approaches with EventEmitters or Services that need to be imported in each ChildComponent.

All I'd like to do, is to set a login-variable from somewhere in the app and change the navigation-display in the main-template according to its login-status. What would be the best practise here? Don't need code examples, just a push in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use router guards that won't allow navigating to the route if the user is not logged in. I blogged about guarding routes here: https://yakovfain.com/2016/07/20/angular-2-guarding-routes/

Comment: That comes very handy, will look into that, thanks! Right now I'm still a step prior to that -> Just cosmetical changes in the main-template dependant on that variable-status.